# Name for natural norm on functions to non-linear targets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, terminology, norms

Is there a standard term for the quasi-norm
$$\|f\|_{[k]}=\sum_{i=1}^k(\sup\|f^{(i)}\|)^{1/i}$$
?

It is useful due to the fact that it is reasonably compatible with post-composition by smooth functions:
$$\|F(f)\|_{[k]}\leq\mathrm{const}_{F,k}\cdot\|f\|_{[k]}$$
in contrast to the usual $C^k$ norm for which this inequality does not hold.

Comment: This seems similar to the definition of Gevrey classes?